# MVC4 Forms Authentication against AD

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I am trying to setup an intranet MVC app that authenticates against our company's AD with forms authentication; we do want the user to have to login.  I am getting the following exception when posting to the Login action: "To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider"."  Anyone else had this problem?

Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://example.domain.com/DC=example,DC=domain,DC=com"/>
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
  <add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="45" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All"/>
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

AccountController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        //The call to WebSecurity.Login is what throws
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Are you using WebMatrix? I haven't used it myself, but could it be that you can't use WebMatrix with ActiveDirectory? If you don't add the enableSimpleMembership key do you still get the problem? Looking at the code for the WebSecurity class using DotPeek I can see this comment, which doesn't quite match your app setting: `// Allow use of <add key="EnableSimpleMembershipKey" value="false" /> to disable registration of membership/role providers as default.`

Comment: It is a brand new project using the MVC4 w/ Forms Auth template in VS2012.  With "enableSimpleMembership" = true, the exception is still thrown.

Comment: Changing "enableSimpleMembership" to "EnableSimpleMembershipKey" also has no effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Created an MVC3 site in VS2010 and got it working with the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider. Then changed the MVC4 AccountController to use the old System.Web.Security instead of WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.

from:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}
```

to:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid && Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My login was working.  It was my logout that wasn't working.  In any case, I changed WebSecurity.Logout() to  FormsAuthentication.SignOut() and that worked.